# Netbeans using minGW doesn't reconize system on compile

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, mingw

I am using netbeans with minGW and msys on windows to code C++. The first day that I installed everything, something like    `system("PAUSE");` would work fine. I go to my computer today which I hadn't turned off, go to the project that I had already and complied coded tried to run it again and it gives me this,

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:19: error: 'system' was not declared in this scope  
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory /c/Users/Grant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2  
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Grant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
```

I can't figure out whats wrong with it and this code is due on Wensday. Please help.

Comment: No, thanks. I didn't know I needed it.

Comment: If your question is solved, please post your solution as an answer and accept it (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<cstdlib>` is required for netbeans to compile  the code.